# python tcp socket dead loop when using blocking recv()

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

Here is my server app:

```
import socket, sys

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 1060))
sock.listen(1)
print("Server is ready to receive.")
s, sockname = sock.accept()
while True:
    data = s.recv(100)
    # dead lock happens without following 'if'
    #if not data:
        #break
    print("The client from {} said: {}".format(s.getpeername(), 
    data.decode("utf-8")))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

And here is the client:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("127.0.0.1", 1060))
print("client is ready")
message = '''Hello, server, my name is client!
         Here is oversize message: saasdasdas
         asdasdasdasssasdasdasdasdasdacsdvas
         sdavsdvavsdavxcvxczvdsavsavadsvasdv
         xcavdasvdsavewavwvdsvdsavasdvdsavad
         sdavsvxcvdavawevsdavsdavsavwevsdvsa
         dsvasdvadsvdasvsdavsadvasdvsdavsdvv
         sacascascwdqdadqwdqwdqwdsadwqdqwdqw
         '''
data = message.encode("utf-8")
sock.sendall(data)
print("I have sent a message of {} length, now I want to close the 
sock!".format(len(data)))
sock.close()
```

The message's length(391bytes) is longer than the server socket receive buffer(100 bytes).

**If I don not adding:**

```
if not data:
    break
```

When client sends data to server, the server's output is:

```
The client from ('127.0.0.1', 63758) said:
The client from ('127.0.0.1', 63758) said:
The client from ('127.0.0.1', 63758) said:
The client from ('127.0.0.1', 63758) said:
The client from ('127.0.0.1', 63758) said:
(...dead loop...)
```

The method `recv()` here is blocking, it can receive 100 bytes from socket buffer once.

**In my mind, the server will receive 4 times until the data is
sent out and when all data has been sent out, the server app will be blocked at `data = s.recv(100)` and wait for next data**.

**But the truth is not just like that. And I am also puzzled that now that it seems a non-blocking `recv()`, why not print the `data.decode("utf-8")`?**

Comment: from what i can tell while true is what is causing this problem. The client closes the connection. At that moment s.recv() is no longer blocking cause there is no connection but you are in a infinite loop, so it keeps printing the string. data is just null so the rest of the code keeps working.

Comment: @rinn2883 Yeah! Exactly where the problem is. And one more fatal is the sendall() method will send a ‘None type’ to server when finishes. I used time.sleep() in the server and actually saw the original output but the dead loop moves quickly printing ‘None type’ so that I misunderstood that there is no output from terminal :)

Comment: sendall() just return None type in client but not sending it to server. When the client’s sock is closed, the recv() in server will become non-blocking and will return None type